# Filter a Drupal View by a Taxonomy Term Reference

Tags: views

I have a view that generates a block on all taxonomy term pages under a specific vocabulary (lets call this vocabulary 'pages' for now). That specific vocabulary has a field added that is a term reference to a a vocabulary we can call 'pagetype' (you can only select one value). I want my view to display all 'pages' that have the same 'pagetype' as the one that I am currently on. The problem is I cannot figure out how to use the current term's 'pagetype' for the contextual filter instead of the current term ID. Any help with this would be awesome.

Answer (score 2):

1. Create view (block)
2. Add fields (title, a small image, date, whatever you like). Or teasers, what works as well.
3. “**Arguments**” is from now on called “**Contextual filters**”, so go there.
4. Add the filters: “**Content: Has taxonomy term ID (with depth)**” and “**Content: Has taxonomy term ID depth modifier**”
5. Configuration on this filter: → When the filter value is NOT in the URL: → Provide default value → Type: Taxonomy Term ID from URL → under that, check the box “Load default filter from node page, that’s good for related taxonomy blocks.” → now check the boxes of the taxonomies you want involved here
6. Now you need to add the second filter in order to exclude the current node from the list. Click **[+]** button of the contextual filters section.
7. Select **Content: Nid**
8. Set the ‘**when argument is not present**’ to ‘**Provide default argument**’
9. Set the ‘**Default argument type**’ to ‘**Content ID from URL**’
10. Go to “**MORE**” , and check the “**Exclude**” box.
11. Move the filter “**Content: Nid**” to the top position.
12. Add a block to your view and embed the block on your node pages
13. Save your view

Answer (score 0):

Try out [Taxonomy Term Reference Filter by Views](http://drupal.org/project/term_reference_filter_by_views) module:

> Add Views Settings for a Taxonomy Term Reference Field Instance to
>   filter the available terms for the field widget form input. inspired
>   from Views integration of Entity reference field widgets.

Comment: "Note: It has nothing to do Views Filters."